# Using host direct children in CSS with Angular4

Tags: css, angular, css-selectors

In my app.component.css I have the following:

```
* ~ * {
  margin-top: 24px;
}
```

which does apply some margin-top to all elements following the first one.
This is not quite what I want, as I only need to target the direct children of my host.
So I did the following :

```
:host > * ~ :host > * {
  margin-top: 24px;
}
```

Unfortunately that doesn't do anything. What am I missing here ?

Comment: The styles of your component are about styling the component itself, not siblings or other components outside the current component. So I don't think this is even supposed to work. You would need to add this style to the parent component.

Comment: Can you please try to explain better what you exactly want to happen, instead (or in addition to) what you not want?

Comment: I think you need to replace the 2nd `:host` with the actual selector (tag name) of your component. I don't know how to address the direct children of a component, because you need to use `::ng-deep` to pierce through the component boundary and use `>` to address direct children. I don't know if and how these can be combined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need one `:host >` — the sibling combinator will relate the two `*` selectors for you:

```
:host > * ~ *
```

This reads as

> Select any element
>   that is a following sibling of any element
>   that is a child of the host element.

... which implies that the subject of the selector is a child of the same host element as the element that it follows, since that's what the word "sibling" means.

Comment: To me it looks like he tries to address recursive children (childs are the same component types as current component) but it's not really clear.

Comment: @Günter Zöchbauer: "This is not quite what I want, as I only need to target the direct children of my host." I read that as the asker wants to apply the `* ~ *` logic only to children of the host element. Seems fairly clear to me.

Comment: The answer was exactly what I was looking for. Cheers to both of u